# Does running laptop on AC with battery degrades battery?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life, maintenance

I am using a laptop for long periods of time with battery on and plugged to AC. Does this degrade my battery? The battery gets charged to 100% and stays at it for the remainder of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. 
The best for a battery is to use it once a month until it depletes to about 50% then reconnect the charger again.
Note: if your battery is 95% or more, the charger will not charge further, when the battery is 94% or lower the charging starts to 100%.

Comment: Just a qualifier -- if it's a very old laptop with NiCad batteries, keeping those charged and rarely operating from the battery can shorten the battery life.

Comment: And another:  with some laptops, you can set the max charge percentage in software.

Comment: Nah, its a brand new Li Ion battery. I am also aware that memory effect is essentially gone nowadays.